# Check if drop-down has more than 1 option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down which is being populated on change of some other checkboxes, so on load the drop-down is empty(has only 1 option "Select" in it).

```
<select id="A" aria-invalid="false">
    <option disabled="" value="0">Select</option>
</select>
```

On check of check-box the value will be added to a drop-down and on un-check of a check-box value will be removed from the drop-down.

I have written a logic for that already. What I am looking for is how do I check if dropdown has any options added to it. ie. on check of a check box I want to display the dropbox if that's the first option added to it else hide the drop-down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `option` length;

```js
var optionsLen = $('#A option').length;

document.write('<br />Number of Options = ' + optionsLen);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="A" aria-invalid="false">
  <option disabled="" value="0">Select</option>
</select>
```

---

If you want number of options which are not disabled.

```js
var optionsLen = $('#A option:not(:disabled)').length;

document.write('<br />Number of Options = ' + optionsLen);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="A" aria-invalid="false">
  <option disabled="" value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alert($('#A option').length)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uy9x8k1e/)

Use the id of select as select and select the option then get the length of by using `.length`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert($('#A option').length)
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/uy9x8k1e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here, this checks how many children there are, you just need to add an if condition or something similar and it's done

https://jsfiddle.net/z8ub6d01/

html:

```
<select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Select</option>
</select>
<span id="foo"></span>
```

jquery/js:

```
var $children = $('select').children();
$('#foo').html("You have " + $children.length + " children");
```